# After merge, VS looking in wrong directory path for a .cs file

Tags: visual-studio-2013, merge, filepath

This error "Source file 'Code\DataAccess\RDB.cs' not found, started after a merge. No files were ever located here nor was it ever used.

[image]

Folder :

I'm not sure whats needed to help fix this issue, so I've provided you with the Folder the actual RDB file it is looking for is located at. (1)

The Folder it is looking in (2).

(3) was for me, last ditch effort to edit the project file but no location or RDB file is mentioned in it.

Comment: Sounds like you have a broken file path in your .csproj? Have you checked this?

Comment: @Mi.Sharp Well I looked into all my project files, and couldn't find that strange path within them. I have since re-branched and moved my code over and everything worked great, would be nice to know if this is fixable however as it was a lot of code to move over into a new branch.

Comment: Ok another try may be to delete the .suo file.

Comment: @Mi.Sharp, *Applause*. can't believe i missed that. Care to make that an answer?

Comment: Great that this helped, your welcome. I posted this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete the .suo file. This fixed this issue for me.

The .suo file contains information about user specific information like breakpoints, state of solution explorer and user settings files. My experience is, that this file contains wrong pathes afer a merge from source control.

When you open your solution next time, this file will be created new by visual studio.